# import data from Excel /CSV file to in angularjs json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have a user upload an Excel /CSV file from their computer then convert it to JSON. I am needing these files as JSON. I have it so they can upload a CSV to JSON. Now I am wanting Excel /CSV  to JSON. Any advice or guidance on this would be appreciated. This needs to be done using angularJS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to read the data in however you want (File Reader, Ajax call, etc.) and then parse the data using Regular Expressions. Then when you have a string, use JSON parse

this isn't my code but here is a snippet of the linked jsfiddle

```
function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");
  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp((
  // Delimiters.
  "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +
  // Quoted fields.
  "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +
  // Standard fields.
  "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"), "gi");
  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];
  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;
  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec(strData)) {
  ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/AZFvQ/